# Bitcoin Recovery Email or Hard Drive

Tags: wallet-recovery, wallet.dat

I received 100 bitcoins from a donor around 2009 but do not remember name of donor, their email address or password etc to recover the bitcoins! Any suggestions or advice?

I am seeking someone to assist.

Comment: When you say you "received" the money, what do you mean?  Did someone transfer the money to a wallet that you control?  Right now, you are being too vague for anyone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you had the donor's name and email, it would not help you recover the bitcoins. You need to get access to the private key.